# Special case of numerical integration over two variables

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to perform an integral involving the function $f(r,\theta)$ where I first compute $\int_0^{2\pi} f(r,\theta) e^{i m \theta} \, \text{d} \theta$. Then I square the modulus of this result, multiply by $r$, and then integrate over some finite interval in $r$. Here, $m$ is a constant.

Is there a way to do this with `NIntegrate` in Mathematica? I do not know how to do numerical integration where one holds the value of $r$ as variable in the first integral and then, prior to the second numerical integration, takes the absolute value squared of the integrand.

One way I can imagine doing this is to define

```
hold[r_, m_] :=  NIntegrate[f[r, theta] Exp[I m theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and then calculating

```
Nintegrate[Abs[hold[r, m]]^2 r, {r, 0, R}],
```

where I would insert a numerical value for $m$ and $R$. However, this gives several error messages during evaluation before giving a result. I am unsure if I can trust the result.

Comment: One thing is that you probably want to use [`?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) on the arguments of `h[]`.

Comment: Of course, problems with code usually require the code: What is a typical function for `f[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`? NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) on the arguments of `h`.  Then assuming `f` is analytic and periodic of period `2 Pi` in `theta`, use the `"Trapezoidal"` method. If `f` is not periodic, then do not use it.  If `f` is not analytic, then give an example; "unhappy functions are unhappy in their own way," to paraphrase *Anna Karenina.*

```
hold[r_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[f[r, theta] Exp[I m theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, Method -> "Trapezoidal"];
Block[{f, R = 2, m = 3},
 f[r_, t_] = 
  TransformedField[ "Cartesian" -> "Polar", x^2 y + y^2 x, {x, y} -> {r, t}];
 NIntegrate[Abs[hold[r, m]]^2 r, {r, 0, R}]
 ]
(*  39.4784  *)
```

Comment: The function in question is indeed periodic in theta and this solution works very well for it.